# MapBox Android invalidate layout when parent view change size

Tags: android, mapbox

I have frameLayout with a child MapBoxView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapBoxMapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:access_token="@string/accessTokenMapBox"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I change size of parent view, but MapView did not update layout

I try call requsetLayout(), try invalidateLayout() - no effect.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping your FrameLayout within a LinearLayout so it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myfirstglapp.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapBoxMapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            mapbox:access_token="@string/accessTokenMapBox"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Unless you plan on adding objects such as a button on top of the mapView layout, the FrameLayout can be removed however. If you are changing a position of a object or size during runtime, using `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` instead of FrameLayout might help as well.

Comment: If you're still having issues with this I can help if you post your java code that changes the layout. Right now with the code you posted I see no issues.